# Arquivos .js não são carregados após ActionLink carregar PartialView

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma PartialView chamada _MenuLeft que contém os meus itens do menu, ela é carregada no _Layout com o Helper Html.Partial(""). Dentro dos 'li'do menu há um ActionLink para carregar na div "conteudo" os formulários que desejo, segue o exemplo:

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Empreendimento", "FormRegisterEmprendimento", "Empreendimento", new AjaxOptions()
                        {
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "conteudo"
                        })
```

O formulário está sendo carregado normalmente mas, dentro da PartialView (formulários) preciso carregar dois .js que fazem a validação dos campos:

```
<script src='~/Content/assets/libs/bootstrap-validator/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js'  type='text/javascript'><\/script>;
<script src='~/Content/assets/js/pages/form-validation.js' type='text/javascript'><\/script>;
```

Como testes eu já os adicionei no fim da PartialView (formulários) e em outro momento dentro dos Bundles e adicionei dentro da section script, mas mesmo assim não carregou os .js.

Comment: Essa partial é apenas para "organização" do código, ou seja, é chamada apenas na view `_Layout`?

Comment: @Randrade Sim é para facilitar a manutenção.

Comment: Então chame seus scripts na view `_Layout`. Só chame um script em uma partial, quando o uso do mesmo for realmente necessário.

Answer (score 0):

Não deveria carregar mesmo pois sua página já foi renderizada.
Considere carregar esses js na _Layout ou tente fazer o append do js através de uma função jQuery.
Veja este link: [Add CSS and JS in AJAX-loaded PartialView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566180/add-css-and-js-in-ajax-loaded-partialview)